# in plaintext vs. as plaintext

Tags: word-choice, grammar

When referring to a password that is to be stored somewhere, what is the correct way:
Store the password *in* plaintext OR Store the password *as* plaintext?

Google searching different variations of this phrase, gives the *in* variant an almost consistent 10:1 ratio.

On the other hand, grammatically, using *as* seems (to me) more correct.

My theory is that the *as* variant is the correct way, but the *in* variant is used more commonly with an implicit *form* that comes after *plaintext*

e.g. Store the password in plaintext *(form)*

Comment: They're both OK. The words can also be separated, plain text.

Comment: In this context, *plain text* is not really the same as *plaintext*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the field of cryptography, which relevant to your context of passwords, [*plaintext*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext) (noun) is a technical term referring to the message that has not been encrypted. It is contrasted with *ciphertext*, which refers to the encrypted message. The separated form [plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) is somewhat different and does not relate specifically to cryptography, so will be ignored in this answer.

Both forms *in/as plaintext* are grammatical, but mean different things. Storing the password *as* plaintext means that the password is stored without encryption. Storing the password *in* plaintext can have the same meaning, but it can also be read as an attempt at [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), or hiding things in plain sight (for example, by inserting the password as an extra word in a given sentence).

With the addition of the word *form*, the word *in* now applies to *form* rather than *plaintext*, so *in plaintext form* carries the same meaning as *as plaintext*, as you suggest.

You asked in comments about a 10:1 ratio in favour of *in plaintext*. Since *in plaintext* includes and goes beyond the semantic range of *as plaintext*, this is perhaps not as surprising as it might first seem. Also, *stored in plaintext* parallels common phrases such as *stored in lists* (or other data structures) and *stored in the cookie jar*, and *in plaintext* sounds identical to the separated form *in plain text*, which parallels the common expression *in plain sight*. All these are plausible reasons for authors to think of the *in* form when writing. We're now crossing heavily into psychology, so I'll leave it at that.

**TL;DR** In answer to your question, *as plaintext* expresses your intent better than *in plaintext*.

Comment: Thanks.
What would explain the 10:1 ratio I've noticed?
In all the cases I checked, the word form did not appear after and I assume most do not actually relate to "embedding" the password in the plaintext

Comment: @dankilman You're welcome. I've added a paragraph to my answer regarding your follow-up question about the 10:1 ratio, but I don't have anything definitive to say on that point.

Comment: Nice of you to consider steganography to make a distinction between in and as.